# Is the space inside a demiplane considered "outdoors" for the purposes of Control Weather?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes, weather

The *demiplane* spell creates a door that leads to another plane of existence:

> You create a shadowy door on a flat solid surface that you can see within range. The door is large enough to allow Medium creatures to pass through unhindered. When opened, the door leads to a demiplane that appears to be an empty room 30 feet in each dimension, made of wood or stone. [...]

It seems that this room is the entirety of this plane. There is nothing beyond the ceiling, floor, or walls. In a sense, the ceiling is the limit of the "sky," although if it has weather is questionable.

Given all this, is the space inside a demiplane considered "outdoors" for the purposes of the *control weather* spell? *Control weather* requires that:

> [...] You must be outdoors to cast this spell. Moving to a place where you don't have a clear path to the sky ends the spell early.

Answer (score 22):

## No, you cannot cast *control weather* inside a room.

As you've quoted, your demiplane is a room made of wood or stone.

When there are no mechanical in-rules definitions, we generally go with the normal language. In this case, in normal language rooms are indoors, it's what makes them rooms. Being outdoors is not being in a room.

It doesn't matter that the entire demiplane is this room, it is still a room. The demiplane is not an entire world, just an extradimensional space.

### Comparison to another extradimensional spell

This is similar to *mordenkainen's magificent mansion*, which also creates an extradimensional space. Both the room of the *demiplane* and the mansion from *magnificent mansion* are indoor structures. They aren't outside so therefore don't pass the gate required for casting *control weather*.

Answer (score 6):

## The demiplane created by this spell is indoors, but other demiplanes might have outdoors areas.

One of the most well-known demiplanes is Ravenloft, the Demiplane of Dread, which contains a wide variety of indoor and outdoor locations within its boundaries. While this spell is limited to creating a single room, similar [spells](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/spells/genesis.htm) or [abilities](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/genesis.htm) from previous editions allowed the caster more freedom in how the demiplane was designed, and monster/NPC abilities don't need to follow the same rules as those of PCs; as a result, if a character were to find themselves in a demiplane that possesses an outdoors area (either as a result of its natural nature, or being designed by a creature that possessed the power to do so), then they would be able to cast Call Lightning.

Answer (score 2):

> the door leads to a demiplane that appears to be an empty room 30 feet in each dimension, made of wood or stone. [...]

**appears to be**

Nothing states outright that the room IS the demiplane. This is an assumption made based on a description of a perception.

So for a purely rules based answer, you KNOW you are in a room, you do NOT know that there is not an 'outside' to this room, visa vi, you can only assume you are indoors.

Comment: Couldn't you be in the middle of a vast outdoor expanse with illusory walls and ceiling around you?

Comment: @Mohirl Honestly if I were a DM, and I got this question, my answer would be "Knock it off." Because that's the only actually reasonable answer to this question. But we passed the realm of sensible some time ago, so, we're now in the realm of nonsensical answers to nonsensical questions.